# how to automate the generation of certificates through certbot?

Tags: python, subprocess, fastapi, system, certbot

How can you automate this process with python  use fast a for a convenient call from another server, how can I do this?

I tried to do it with subprocess.run and Popen but nothing happened the certificate doesn't appear and i don't know

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.